# Angular UI-Router Help - Show Elements Based On State

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-show

First off I am new to angular and I am inheriting this project.  This seems like it should be deathly easy to say if the state is this show this, but I keep failing :]

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('page1', {
                url: '/page1',
                data: etc..................
                },


.state('page1.nest', {
                    url: '/page1/nest',
                    data: etc..................
                    },
.state('page2', {
                        url: '/page2',
                        data: etc..................
                        },
```

Each page has it's own controller.  page1 and page1 nest share the same templateUrl: 'scripts/app/page.html'.  The div below lives on the page.html.

How do I simple say...

```
<div>
  <span ng-show="if state == page1">Page 1</span>
  <span ng-show="if state == page1/nest">Page 1 Nest</span>
</div>
<div>
 Same Content on both here
</div>
```

I think it has something to do with $stateParams needing to be exposed to the scope in the controller?

Comment: I think you are missing how ui-router works.  You use the states to define which views will be used.  There is no need to "test" the state.  UI-Router does that for you.  It's also not clear as to where this `div` is in the entire structure.

Comment: @ewahner Add some extra info.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the $state service provided by UI-Router

[Check the documentation out here.](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateobject.html#is)

You'll do something like

In your controller. Inject $state then set it to a scope variable

```
$scope.state = $state
```

Then you can do something like this.

```
<span ng-show="state.is('page1')">Page 1</span>
```

Alternatively obviously you can use a function in your controller.

```
<span ng-if="inState('page1')">Page 1</span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.inState = function(state){
    return $state.is(state);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I knew it had to be easy.  Works like a charm.  I was jacking with  $stateParams and failing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start first by formatting your code a little better and closing parens where they should be closed.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('page1', {
                    url: '/page1',
                    template: 'templates/page1.html',
                    data: etc..................
                }),
                .state('page1.nest', {
                    url: '/page1/nest',
                    template: 'templates/page1.nest.html',
                    data: etc..................
                }),
                .state('page2', {
                    url: '/page2',
                    template: 'templates/page2.html',
                    data: etc..................
                });
```

Typically you would have these various templates somewhere in your project structure like

```
/app
    /templates
```

Then you have your index page...

```
<html ng-app>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ui-view></div> <!-- this is where the page1 or page2 state gets loaded -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your page1 or page2 html files

```
<div>
 ... content goes here ...
    <div ui-view></div> <!-- nested content will go in here -->
</div>
```

Then in your page1.nest.html

```
<div>
... all your nested content goes here
</div>
```